# I dont know how to set my grid container properly

Tags: html, css

I have a question which i cant get my head around. I am a bum.
Basically I have this code:

```
<style>
.grid-container {
    height: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
    "text text ."
    "text text text"
    "text text text";
     
}

#myText {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="grid-container">
         <div id="myText"></div>
          <img src="Images/grad3.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

I want a grid container that looks like this:

TEXT | TEXT | IMAGE

TEXT | TEXT | TEXT

TEXT | TEXT | TEXT

for some reason with this code, text only displays in the first 2 columns, but not in the "squares" bellow image.
If there is anyone willing to help, it would be appreciated!

I tried changing the values, whole code, googling stuff but for some reason nothing worked.

I am sorry, I didnt think it was important when i wrote the question, but  this whole php file is essentially a popup window, that opens when user
click on an image. Then, text "writes itself with this code:

```
<script>
var textInterval;
var textWritten = false;

function showPopup(element) {
document.getElementById("background-blur").style.display = "block";
$(element).siblings('.island1-popup').show("show");
var textIndex = 0;
var text = "This is the first line of text. " + 
       "This is the second line of textThis is the first line of 
text. " + 
       "This is the second line of textvvThis is the first line of 
text. " + 
       "This is the second line of textThis is the first line of 
text. " + 
       "This is the second line of textvvThis is the first line of 
text. " + 
       
       "This is the second line of textSEZAM.";
var textSpeed = 5; // this is in milliseconds
var textElement = document.getElementById("myText");

if (textWritten) {
    return;
}

textInterval = setInterval(function () {
    textElement.textContent += text[textIndex];
    textIndex++;

    if (textIndex === text.length) {
        clearInterval(textInterval);
        textWritten = true;
        }
    }, textSpeed);
}

function hidePopup(element) {
document.getElementById("background-blur").style.display = "none";
$(element).closest('.island1-popup').hide("show");
clearInterval(textInterval);
</script>
```

Probably thats the issue why areas dont work, i tried all possible combinations but as i said, text appears only in first 2 columns, and the image in the top right square i guess takes also the whole 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO!

You have created a **3x3 grid** and if you want the third item to be an image you will have to put at least three items in the grid, the third being an image.

When you define a `grid-template-areas` you will have to assign the defined names to specific items in the grid, otherwise the property will have no effect.

Check out [Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/) which has an elaborate list examples for you to try out...

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }

body { margin: 0; padding: 0.5rem }

.grid-container {
    height: 1100px; /* don't use fixed units */
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);

    gap: 0.5rem;

/* grid-template-areas has no effect when you don't assign them to an item */

/*
    grid-template-areas: 
    "text text ."
    "text text text"
    "text text text";
*/
}

.myText {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid Gray;

    /* For easy centering of content */
    display: grid; place-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}

/* To scale the image */
img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="myText">in a 3x3 grid, you need to define 9 elements</div>
    <div class="myText">text 1</div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/356?random">
    <div class="myText">text 2</div>
    <div class="myText">text 3</div>
    <div class="myText">text 4</div>
    <div class="myText">text 5</div>
    <div class="myText">text 6</div>
    <div class="myText">text 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, i edited my main question because i realised there was an important part that i didnt mention at first! If you have time, please check it out!

Comment: The crux of your issue is that your *third* element inside `.grid-container` needs to be an `img` or an element containing an image. Whether it is a 'normal' document or a 'modal' is not relevant. Also, the `<script>` you inserted contains references to `background-blur` and `.island1-popup` which are not in the HTML and CSS you posted. As I shown I my example, `.grid-container` is defined as a **3x3 grid**, so it needs to have nine child elements (div, p, span, etc.) of which the 3rd needs to be an image in this case.